# Question about motor and generator size

Tags: motor, generator

For a given power, which will be larger, a motor or a generator? Is there a certain relationship between motor/generator size and power?

Comment: Here's [another question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/402283/do-electric-motors-have-the-same-efficiency-when-operating-as-generators) that is very related to your question. If the efficiency is nearly identical, then that also means that the powers will be nearly identical and therefor also the sizes will be nearly identical. - I won't make an answer because an answer should be able to stand on its own, not depend on another answer from another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any electrical motor is also an electrical generator. The current flow and torque direction depends on the difference of the voltage applied and the mechanical speed applied from outside.

As the losses have to be supplied by the driving side, it depends whether you talk about electrical power or mechanical power.

- If you talk about electrical power, the generator has to be slightly bigger, because the mechanical part has to supply all the electrical losses.
- If you talk about mechanical power, the motor has to be slightly bigger, because the electrical part has to supply all the mechanical losses.